# Getting parse error in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to left join tables to display results ,
and my query is the following :

```
$select= k_people,k_loans,k_loan_types CONCAT(customer.first_name,customer.last_name) as customer_name, 
                   CONCAT(agent.first_name,agent.last_name) as agent_name, 
                   CONCAT(approver.first_name,approver.last_name) as approver_name,
                   k_loan_types.name as k_loan_type FROM k_loans
       LEFT join k_people as customer', 'customer.person_id = k_loans.customer_id,

    LEFT join k_people as agent', 'agent.person_id = k_loans.loan_agent_id,
       LEFT join k_people as approver', 'approver.person_id = k_loans.loan_approved_by_id,
       LEFT join k_loan_types', 'k_loan_types.loan_type_id = k_loans.loan_type_id;
      $result= mysqli_query($con,select($select));
```

but it throws the following error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/xXx/

Can anyone help me understand wat I am doin wrong , my MYSQL query knowledge is very limited and trying to learn by doin .

UPDATE : after applying suggestions in the comment the query looks like the following :

```
$select=SELECT k_people,k_loans,k_loan_types CONCAT(customer.first_name,customer.last_name) as customer_name, 
                   CONCAT(agent.first_name,agent.last_name) as agent_name, 
                   CONCAT(approver.first_name,approver.last_name) as approver_name,
                   k_loan_types.name as k_loan_type FROM k_loans
       LEFT join k_people as customer ON customer.person_id = k_loans.customer_id,
       LEFT join k_people as agent ON agent.person_id = k_loans.loan_agent_id,
       LEFT join k_people as approver ON approver.person_id = k_loans.loan_approved_by_id,
       LEFT join k_loan_types ON k_loan_types.loan_type_id = k_loans.loan_type_id;
      $result= mysqli_query($con,$select);
```

Error changed to : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'kpos_people' (T_STRING)

Comment: @GordonLinoff a variable , to store the long query and then selecting it in $result= mysqli_query($con,select($select));

Comment: We also require on after left join . Below is an example $query_Recordset1 = "   SELECT * FROM tbgastos   LEFT JOIN tbconceptosgastos    ON tbgastos.tipoGasto = tbconceptosgastos.idConceptoGasto  LEFT JOIN tbobras    ON tbgastos.obra = tbobras.idObra  LEFT JOIN tbproveedores   ON tbgastos.proveedor = tbproveedores.idProveedor  ORDER BY fecha DESC "; also your query should look something like above which starts from select even if you are storing it in a variable

Comment: @LearningPhase now its giving Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'k_people' (T_STRING) in

Comment: the commas after each join are not needed and likely the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Niagaradad Still same ...

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the extra ' in your query after your fields names. they are not required

```
select= k_people,k_loans,k_loan_types CONCAT(customer.first_name,customer.last_name) as customer_name, 
                   CONCAT(agent.first_name,agent.last_name) as agent_name, 
                   CONCAT(approver.first_name,approver.last_name) as approver_name,
                   k_loan_types.name as k_loan_type FROM k_loans
       LEFT join k_people as customer, customer.person_id = k_loans.customer_id,

    LEFT join k_people as agent,agent.person_id = k_loans.loan_agent_id,
       LEFT join k_people as approver, approver.person_id = k_loans.loan_approved_by_id,
       LEFT join k_loan_types, k_loan_types.loan_type_id = k_loans.loan_type_id;
      $result= mysqli_query($con,select($select));
```

Comment: @phpnewbie did you remove all of them?

Comment: I copy pasted the code from ur answer